# Obscure Mio Tablet Stuck when Booting to Bootloader

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, bootloader, tablet

In my journey to turn my extremely weak and unsupported Mio Tablet 10 into a Linux machine, I've come across a hurdle when trying to boot into bootloader mode from either ADB or the recovery menu on the tablet.

**When booting to Fastboot, the tablet just freezes on the OEM splash screen (Mio's Logo) and doesn't move on from there.** It can boot normally and works as expected, so I don't believe there is anything corrupted (I've also barely touched this tablet since getting it, so I don't expect anything to be broken yet).

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot it? (`adb logcat` doesn't pick anything up, and just says it is waiting for a device). The tablet is running Android 6.

P.S if anyone has a way to root the tablet without using bootloader, it'll also be much appreciated.